# How to get PC Model type?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is there a function or some method to get a PC's Model type? In my case this would be "OptiPlex 780". Until now i queryd it from WMI (WIN32_Computersystem), and it worked in 99% of the cases, but sometimes, it couldn't retrieve the Model. So WMI isn't an option for me. I'm looking for an other way. 
Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I've built my own machine from parts. What would the "Model type" be?

Comment: @Anon: Good question :) In my company we are using only Dell PC's. So this shouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: @Anon: Perhaps your PC will be of 'Clone' type :) Thats what we used to call.. Brand PC and Clone PC

Comment: When it can't retrieve model, how is it failing?  With an error code, blank string?

Comment: With a blank string. And if i query it manually using "wmic computersystem get model" it doesn't show anything. So there isn't anything in WMI, and that's why my application can't retrieve it. WMI seems to me very very untrustable :(

Comment: @Sarwar: But it's not a "clone" of anything. "Clone" suggests a knockoff, a duplication of a brand-name machine. Constructing a custom machine from parts is completely different.

Comment: @kampi, you say it works in 99% of the cases.  I don't know about the hardware side but I suspect it queries some driver or wotnot.  And if it works in 99% of the cases, perhaps it is the manufacturer at fault?  If so, it's not the WMI call that is un-trustworthy.

Comment: @Anon:  I built my home PC.  Cost 5 grand.  Thrifty, my butt! :)

Comment: @John: To be fair, it was still probably cheaper than outright buying a same-specced machine.

Comment: If WMI can't do it why do you think anything else will? It doesn't sound like it would be hard to work around. If the model type comes back as unrecognised then look it up in a pre-prepared table indexed on MAC address.

Comment: @David: There has to be an other way, because windows can it query. Ok, i don't know from where windows querys it, but for example if you type "dxdiag" in run, then you can see there the System Model too. And if dxdiag would query it from WMI too, than sometimes it also couldn't retrieve it on some machines as i said before.

Comment: @kampi dig about in the registry and see if you can find the string and then write some special code to do that via WMI remote registry read in the case where the string comes back empty

Comment: @David: i have thought about this idea too, but in the registry there can't be found neither. On some machines it can be found somewhere in the registry but on some it can't. :(

Comment: @kampi dxdiag has to get is from somewhere

Comment: @David: Yes, that's what i want to know :) Tomorrow i will dig the whole registry. Maybe i missed something.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's documentation, `Model` must always be filled in:

> Model
>
> Data type: string
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Product name that a manufacturer gives
>   to a computer. This property must have
>   a value.

Perhaps the times it doesn't work is when you're logged in to a non-administrator account?

> Most access to WMI is restricted to
>   Administrator accounts but
>   non-Administrator accounts have some
>   access on the local computer.